# ImageMagick won't show Ghostscipt as delegate

Tags: delegates, osx-lion, imagemagick, ghostscript

Was trying to get ImageMagick to talk to Ghostscript using MacPorts in OSX Lion but it wouldn't have it. Used to have it working fine under Snow Leopard but something went amiss during Migration assistant.

Anyhow, have unstalled all of Mac Ports and am now trying using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

Have installed Homebrew, installed ImageMagick and then ghostscript. Imagemagick is working fine (using a php image script and MAMP) but Ghostscript is not converting PDF's to jpgs. I can see than 'gs' is not listed as a delegate of Imagemagick.

Here are some relevant Terminal dumps:

```
convert -list delegate

Path: /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/etc/ImageMagick/delegates.xml

Delegate                Command
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    blender =>          "blender" -b "%i" -F PNG -o "%o""\n"convert" -concatenate "%o*.png" "%o"
        cdr =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"
        cgm =>          "ralcgm" -d ps -oC  "%o" 2> "%Z"
        dng:decode =>          "ufraw-batch" --silent --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16 "--output=%u.png" "%i"
        dvi =>          "dvips" -q -o "%o" "%i"
        epsps        "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
        epspdf       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
        fig =>          "fig2dev" -L ps "%i" "%o"
        hpg =>          "hp2xx" -q -m eps -f `basename "%o"` "%i";     mv -f `basename "%o"` "%o"
       hpgl =>          "if [ -e hp2xx -o -e /usr/bin/hp2xx ]; then     hp2xx -q -m eps -f `basename "%o"` "%i";     mv -f `basename "%o"` "%o";   else     echo "You need to install hp2xx to use HPGL files with ImageMagick.";     exit 1;   fi"
        htm =>          "html2ps" -U -o "%o" "%i"
       html =>          "html2ps" -U -o "%o" "%i"
      https =>          "curl" -s -k -o "%o" "https:%M"
       ilbm =>          "ilbmtoppm" "%i" > "%o"
        man =>          "groff" -man -Tps "%i" > "%o"
       miff          "ffmpeg" -v -1 -i "%i" -vframes %S -vcodec pam -an -f rawvideo -y "%u.pam" 2> "%Z"
        pdfeps       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=epswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
        pdfps        "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
        plt =>          "echo" "set size 1.25,0.62; set terminal postscript portrait color solid; set output \'%o\'; load \'%i\'" > "%u";"gnuplot" "%u"
        pnm "%o"
        pov =>          "povray" "+i%i" -D0 "+o%o" +fn%q +w%w +h%h +a -q9 "-kfi%s" "-kff%n";"convert" -concatenate "%o*.png" "%o"
         pseps       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=epswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
         pspdf       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
       rgba          "scanimage" -d "%i" > "%o"
      scanx =>          "scanimage" > "%o"
      shtml =>          "html2ps" -U -o "%o" "%i"
        sid =>          "mrsidgeodecode" -if sid -i "%i" -of tif -o "%o" > "%u"
        svg =>          "rsvg-convert" -o "%o" "%i"
       tiffps        "enscript" -o "%o" "%i"
        wmf =>          "wmf2eps" -o "%o" "%i"
    doms-imac:~ dom$ convert -list delegate | grep --color -E '(eps|pdf)'
        epsps        "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
        epspdf       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
        hpg =>          "hp2xx" -q -m eps -f `basename "%o"` "%i";     mv -f `basename "%o"` "%o"
       hpgl =>          "if [ -e hp2xx -o -e /usr/bin/hp2xx ]; then     hp2xx -q -m eps -f `basename "%o"` "%i";     mv -f `basename "%o"` "%o";   else     echo "You need to install hp2xx to use HPGL files with ImageMagick.";     exit 1;   fi"
        pdfeps       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=epswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
        pdfps        "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
         pseps       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=epswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
         pspdf       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
        wmf =>          "wmf2eps" -o "%o" "%i"


convert -list configure

    Path: /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/ImageMagick/config/configure.xml
    
    Name          Value
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CC            /usr/bin/clang
    CFLAGS        -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread
    CODER_PATH    /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/ImageMagick/modules-Q16/coders
    CONFIGURE     ./configure  '--disable-osx-universal-binary' '--without-perl' '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--enable-shared' '--disable-static' '--with-modules' '--without-magick-plus-plus' 'CC=/usr/bin/clang' 'CFLAGS=-Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.7' 'LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.1.1/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/X11/lib' 'CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.1.1/include -isystem /usr/local/include -I/usr/X11/include' 'CXX=/usr/bin/clang++' 'CXXFLAGS=-Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.7'
    CONFIGURE_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/etc/ImageMagick/
    COPYRIGHT     Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
    CPPFLAGS      -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick
    CXX           /usr/bin/clang++
    CXXFLAGS      -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread
    DEFS          -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
    DELEGATES     bzlib fontconfig freetype jpeg jng jp2 lcms2 png tiff x11 xml zlib
    DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS 'CC=/usr/bin/clang' 'CFLAGS=-Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.7' 'CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.1.1/include -isystem /usr/local/include -I/usr/X11/include' 'CXX=/usr/bin/clang++' 'LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.1.1/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/X11/lib' --disable-deprecated --with-quantum-depth=16 --with-umem=no --with-autotrace=no --with-gslib=no --with-fontpath= --with-wmf=no --with-perl=no
    DOCUMENTATION_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/share/doc/ImageMagick
    EXEC-PREFIX   /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6
    EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/bin
    FEATURES      OpenCL 
    FILTER_PATH   /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/ImageMagick/modules-Q16/filters
    HOST          x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
    INCLUDE_PATH  /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick
    LDFLAGS       -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.1.1/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/X11/lib
    LIB_VERSION   0x677
    LIB_VERSION_NUMBER 6,7,7,6
    LIBRARY_PATH  /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/ImageMagick
    LIBS          -lMagickCore -llcms2 -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -L/usr/X11/lib -lfontconfig -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXt -lbz2 -lz -lm -Wl,-framework,OpenCL -lm -lpthread -lltdl
    NAME          ImageMagick
    PCFLAGS       
    PREFIX        /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6
    QuantumDepth  16
    RELEASE_DATE  2012-08-08
    SHARE_PATH    /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/share/ImageMagick
    SVN_REVISION  8165
    TARGET_CPU    x86_64
    TARGET_OS     darwin11.4.0
    TARGET_VENDOR apple
    VERSION       6.7.7
    WEBSITE       http://www.imagemagick.org
```

How do I force Ghostscript to be seen as a delegate by ImageMagick?

Answer (score 4):

Well, in your listing coming from `convert -list delegate` there are the following six lines:

```
eps<=>ps     "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
eps<=>pdf    "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
pdf<=>eps    "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=epswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
pdf<=>ps     "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
 ps<=>eps    "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=epswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
 ps<=>pdf    "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
```

They all **do** mention `"gs"`...

However, you say you first installed ImageMagick and only *then* Ghostscript.

So ImageMagick could not find any Ghostscript during compile time, that's why it doesn't appear in `convert -list configure | grep DELEG`....

You should try and install in reverse order: **first** Ghostscript, then ImageMagick....

Comment: That sounds like a beautifully simple solution. Unfortunately it hasn't worked. I tried as follows:
    brew remove ghostscript
    brew remove imagemagick
    brew install ghostscript
    brew install imagemagick

I even then tried 'brew install imagemagick --with-gslib'  for the last step but I still end up with 'convert list configure' that shows CONFIGURE '--without-gslib'. Can I manually link IM to GS by adding an entry to delegates.xml file and if yes, what should i add?

Comment: Check if your `./configure [your options]` command had contradictory parameters: where there both, `--with-gslib` as well as `--without-gslib`? You can check by running `head -n 12 config.log` which should show you the `./configure` commandline you did run.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

For latecomers, this is the short version of @Kurt Pfeifle's answer + comment section. Just run

```
brew update \
 && brew reinstall ghostscript \
 && brew reinstall imagemagick --with-ghostscript
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple installations of ImageMagick's convert on your system (maybe because your MacPorts installation wasn't cleanly removed)? To find out, run this commandline (which uses Spotlight search):

```
mdfind convert 2>&1 | grep convert
```

Update your question with the full info coming from these commands:

```
which convert
convert -list configure
convert -version
otool -L $(which convert)
which gsx
which gsc
which gs
gs -version
otool -L $(which gs)
```